# Zend Framework 2, how can I change the layout when 404 happens?

Tags: zend-framework2

Im in module/Application/Module:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager->attach (MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, function (MvcEvent $e) {
    }
}
```

and I have no idea what to do.

Comment: `Zend\Mvc\View\Http\RouteNotFoundStrategy` already does this. It uses the [`not_found_template` configuration key](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L83). Is there any reason you wish add your own?

Comment: The answer here might help -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576428/zf2-event-before-not-found-template/15577445#15577445

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $this->layout('layout/error.phtml'); ?>
```

Just add code above as the first line to your view/error/404.phtml
Don't forget to create error.phtml in layout directory